# PHP DOMXPath has mysteriously stopped working

Tags: php

For some reason that completely escapes me, PHP DOMXPath has stopped working on my machine. As the painfully-trivial example below shows, even obvious cases aren't returning expected results. As you can see, I have removed all dependencies on code that I have written. I'm virtually certain that it's not in something that I wrote. But I can't see any reason why even trivial cases like this aren't working.

This is a major problem as I have a lot of HTML generation code that uses DOMXPath for testing and validation. What's going on?

Test class (simplified for brevity):

```
class TempTest
{
    public function test()
    {
        $document = new \DOMDocument();
        if (!$document->loadHTML("<ul class=\"blah\"></ul>")) throw new \Exception (implode (",", libxml_get_errors()));
        $xpath = new \DOMXPath($document);
        $this->assertEquals(1, $xpath->query('/ul')->length);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) TempTest::test
Failed asserting that 0 matches expected 1.

/Users/mac/Projects/NetShapers/Gears/html/Html/Tests/Unit/Semantic/Exception/TempTest.php:11
```

Comment: Use `//ul` instead.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I reached to the same answer but still can't figure out why.

Comment: I always do `//` but it depends on the tool you use, http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/712bd1503510a8183d37fd3b7c486ee1 shows its fine with `/ul`, domdocument on the other hand does not work, but works with simplexmlelement.. https://3v4l.org/FQkqv just stick with `//` it works with all.

Comment: `/ul` and `//ul` aren't the same query.